# return prefix[str(message.guild.id)] KeyError: '905126423902167041' discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I tried this custom prefix command im almost done with my discord bot i just wanted to make an custom prefix command and i ran the bot it was online but then when i used the command it got this error in the logs:

```
File "main.py", line 22, in get_prefix
    return prefix[str(message.guild.id)]
KeyError: '905126423902167041'
```

the code was:

```
import os
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from webserver import keep_alive
import asyncio
import random
from discord.embeds import Embed
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, CheckFailure
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions
import time
import typing
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.errors import Forbidden
from discord.ext.commands.bot import Bot
import json

def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open("prefixes.json", "r") as f:
        prefix = json.load(f)
    return prefix[str(message.guild.id)]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix, help_command = None)

@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open("prefixes.json", "r") as f:
        prefix = json.load(f)
    prefix[str(guild.id)] = "/"
    with open("prefixes.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(prefix, f, indent=4)


@client.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
    with open("prefixes.json", "r") as f:
        prefix = json.load(f)
    prefix.pop(str(guild.id))
    with open("prefixes.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(prefix, f, indent=4)


@client.command()
async def setprefix(ctx, new: str):
    with open("prefixes.json", "r") as f:
        prefix = json.load(f)
    prefix[str(ctx.guild.id)] = new
    with open("prefixes.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(prefix, f, indent=4)
    await ctx.send(f"New prefix `{new}`")


@client.command()
async def apply(ctx):

  em = discord.Embed(tittle = "Applications", description = "Here are the all roles you can apply for, make sure you meet the requirements.", color = ctx.author.color)

  em.add_field(name = "Trial Application", value = " no links ", inline = False)
  em.add_field(name ="Youtube Application", value = " no links  ", inline = False)
  em.add_field(name ="Developer Application", value = "no links ")

  await ctx.send(embed = em)

@client.command(aliases=['c'])
@has_permissions(manage_messages = True)
async def clear(ctx, amount=2):
  await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount)

@client.group(invoke_without_command=True)
async def help(ctx):

  em = discord.Embed(tittle = "Help", description = "Use ?help <command> for extented info on a command.", color = ctx.author.color)

  em.add_field(name = "Modration", value = "Kick, Ban, Unban, Mute And Unmute")

  em.add_field(name ="Fun", value = "No fun commands yet")

  await ctx.send(embed = em)



@help.command()
async def kick(ctx):

  em = discord.Embed(tittle = "Kick", description = "Kicks a member from the server", color = ctx.author.color)

  em.add_field(name = "Example", value = "?kick {User} {Reason} eg ?Kick Mixu#0720 Get out!")

  await ctx.send(embed = em)

@help.command()
async def ban(ctx):

  em = discord.Embed(tittle = "Ban", description = "Bans a member from the server", color = ctx.author.color)

  em.add_field(name = "Example", value = "?ban {User} {Reason} eg ?ban Mixu#0720 Get out!")

  await ctx.send(embed = em)

@help.command()
async def unban(ctx):

  em = discord.Embed(tittle = "Unban", description = "Unbans a member from the server", color = ctx.author.color)

  em.add_field(name = "Example", value = "?unban {User} {Reason} eg ?unban Mixu#0720 Appealed")

  await ctx.send(embed = em)

@help.command()
async def mute(ctx):

  em = discord.Embed(tittle = "Mute", description = "Mutes a member", color = ctx.author.color)

  em.add_field(name = "Example", value = "?mute {User} {Reason} eg ?mute Mixu#0720 spamming!")

  await ctx.send(embed = em)

@help.command()
async def unmute(ctx):

  em = discord.Embed(tittle = "Unmute", description = "Unmutes a muted member", color = ctx.author.color)

  em.add_field(name = "Example", value = "?unmute {User} {Reason} eg ?unmute Mixu#0720 mute appealed.")

  await ctx.send(embed = em)

@client.command()
@has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    username_1 = ctx.message.author.name
    avatar_1 = ctx.message.author.avatar_url
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f'User {member} has been banned')
    embed.set_author(name=f"Requested By {username_1}", icon_url=avatar_1)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@client.command()
@has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
    username_1 = ctx.message.author.name
    avatar_1 = ctx.message.author.avatar_url
    
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split("#")
    
    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user

        if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            embed=discord.Embed(title=f'Unbanned {user.mention}')
            embed.set_author(name=f"Requested By {username_1}", icon_url=avatar_1)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@client.command()
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    username_1 = ctx.message.author.name
    avatar_1 = ctx.message.author.avatar_url
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f'User {member} has been kick')
    embed.set_author(name=f"requested by {username_1}", icon_url=avatar_1)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@client.command(description="Mutes the specified user.")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    guild = ctx.guild
    mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")

    if not mutedRole:
        mutedRole = await guild.create_role(name="Muted")

        for channel in guild.channels:
            await channel.set_permissions(mutedRole, speak=False, send_messages=False, read_message_history=True, read_messages=False)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Muted", description=f"{member.mention} was muted ", colour=discord.Colour.light_gray())
    embed.add_field(name="Reason:", value=reason, inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await member.add_roles(mutedRole, reason=reason)
    await member.send(f" you have been muted from: {guild.name} reason: {reason}")

@client.command(description="Unmutes a specified user.")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def unmute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
   mutedRole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")

   await member.remove_roles(mutedRole)
   await member.send(f" you have unmutedd from: - {ctx.guild.name}")
   embed = discord.Embed(title="User Unmuted", description=f" unmuted {member.mention}",colour=discord.Colour.light_gray())
   await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@client.command()
async def tempmute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time: int, d, *, reason=None):
    guild = ctx.guild

    for role in guild.roles:
        if role.name == "Muted":
            await member.add_roles(905765835791036477)

            embed = discord.Embed(title="Muted!", description=f"{member.mention} has been tempmuted ", colour=discord.Colour.light_gray())
            embed.add_field(name="reason:", value=reason, inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="time left for the mute:", value=f"{time}{d}", inline=False)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

            if d == "s":
                await asyncio.sleep(time)

            if d == "m":
                await asyncio.sleep(time*60)

            if d == "h":
                await asyncio.sleep(time*60*60)

            if d == "d":
                await asyncio.sleep(time*60*60*24)

            await member.remove_roles(role)

            embed = discord.Embed(title="Unmute (temp) ", description=f"Unmuted -{member.mention} ", colour=discord.Colour.light_gray())
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            return

my_secret = os.environ['TOKEN']

keep_alive()
client.run(my_secret)
```

please help me out if you can, it would be great if you would, have a nice day.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236 and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to explain your understanding of the error message. If you haven't tried to understand the error message at all, you should do that first. Then try to think of reasons why it might occur. Think carefully about the code that causes the problem (if you don't know which code that is, well, the error message explicitly tells you), and about exactly what it does.

Comment: Then carefully consider: when you read data from `prefixes.json`, what problem are you trying to solve with that data? What keys do you expect the resulting dictionary to have? What key are you trying to look up? Most importantly, *what do you want to happen if the key isn't there*?

Comment: Could you show the `prefixes.json` file?

Comment: @FusionSid just create a file called prefixes.json then in the file make brakets like this {} and leave it as is, the bot should make its own info in the file